# How to create a CentOS mirror from an old point release?

Tags: centos6

I want to [create](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/CreatePublicMirrors) a private mirror for CentOS 6.6. Is there any mirror supporting rsync that provides an old point release? I do know that CentOS [does not recommend](https://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/General) sticking to a point release. This local mirror will be used to ensure that the software that we use is common across several systems. We will update all of them together whenever this is decided.

Comment: If you go to any mirror that has already removed 6.6 and read the readme file it'll point you to vault.centos.org.  If you read the readme there, it has several rsync addresses.

Comment: @yoonix that's exactly what my answer says because guess what I did ...

Comment: I simply cannot understand why this question was voted down. I guess moderator attention is required.

Comment: I voted it down because the answer is easily found with the most minimal of research.  This isn't a technical problem this is a lazy problem.

Comment: I had located [this](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.6/readme) readme that does not mention about rsync. Moreover, I had also provided links to documentation that I had read conveying that I had done my bit. I suppose the inclination to help should be a little more than the tendency to correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The public mirrors have the packages removed. However, they are stored on vault.centos.org so you should be able to get what you want from http://vault.centos.org/6.6/.

The vault [readme.txt](http://vault.centos.org/readme.txt) has this to say on rsync

> The Following External Vault mirrors (not monitored by the CentOS Infra team !) also provide direct downloads for all content, including isos and rsync access:

Comment: Fantastic! I ran `rsync -a -v --exclude=debug rsync://archive.kernel.org/centos-vault/6.6/os/i386 .` and it worked!